# Moped electrics cut out

Tags: electrical, starter

Hello i have had my piaggio skipper for about 4 months and only recently it has stopped working When i turn then ignition key on all of the electrics come on fine, but when i hold the brake and press the start button all electrics turn off and the bike wont start, please helo me as i have no idea what to do, i have relplaced all fuses but hasnt helped and need my bike for work. Many thanks please help

Comment: Have you checked the charge/viability of the battery? A weak battery might have enough juice to light the lights, but not enough to turn the starter.  How bright are the lights (a yellowish/brownish headlight is a indication that the battery is sub-par)

Comment: All of the dash lights and the front/back lights cut out and a quiet winey noise comes from the starter motor area

Comment: That's consistent with what I wrote.  You have a weak battery.  It cannot supply enough current to turn the starter.  Get the battery tested.

Comment: Okay i guess ill just get a new one, thanks alot for the advice!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the charge/viability of the battery? A weak battery might have enough juice to light the lights, but not enough to turn the starter. How bright are the lights (a yellowish/brownish headlight is an indication that the battery is sub-par).

Comment: I agree with what mike65535 says. Auto part stores will typically test your battery for free.